# Recursive function not updating list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that checks if the structure does not stick out of the sphere. Both structure and sphere are in slices represented by numpy arrays. When the structure sticks out i increase the radius by 10% and want to create new structure. Everything seems to work fine except that when i display the structure and sphere the structure still sticks out. It looks like the arrays with the sphere are not updated at all. What can be the reason?

```
sphere_masks = list()
for slice, distance_matrix in self.distance_matrices:
 sphere = distance_matrix <= self.radius
if sphere.any() and smooth:
 sphere = self._smooth_circle(sphere)
sphere_masks.append((slice, sphere))

print("Radius = " + str(self.radius))

sphere_masks_all = list()
[sphere_masks_all.append(np.zeros(np.shape(mask))) for mask in self.series_masks]
sphere_masks_all[sphere_masks[0][0] : (sphere_masks[-1][0] + 1)] = [mask for _, mask in sphere_masks]

if self.sphere_type == "circumscribed":
 for i, struct in enumerate(self.series_masks):
  intersection = np.logical_and(sphere_masks[i][1], struct.astype(bool))
  if np.count_nonzero(struct) != np.count_nonzero(intersection):
   print(str(i))
   self.radius = 1.1 * self.radius
   #function calls itself
   self._create_sphere_masks()

return sphere_masks_all
```

Comment: I figuredit out, i have to return self._create_sphere_masks()!

Answer (score 0):

```
return self._create_sphere_masks()
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation, about why this works, to help future readers.